# bcp export syntax error on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, bcp

I was wondering how to incorporate a parameter in my bcp with stored procedure the error is at line 8 @JDEBatchNumber
any idea how to add this parameter?
thank you

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(500)
Declare @TimeStamp as nvarchar(100) = Replace((CONVERT(varchar(25), getdate(), 121)),':','')
Declare @JDEBatchNumber as float = '566521'
Declare @NumberOfRecords as bigInt = (select count(*) From [JDE_PRODUCTION].[PRODDTA].[F0911] Where GLICU = @JDEBatchNumber)


if @NumberOfRecords > 0
SET @cmd = 'BCP "EXECUTE [F0902].[D365O].[Get-F0911NewRecordsByBatchNumber] '+@JDEBatchNumber+'" QUERYOUT "D:\D365O\DataSource\F0911\Input\'+@TimeStamp+'.csv" -c -t\^, -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME + ''
EXECUTE MASTER..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't concat a float with a + since it tries to add it... just cast it first.

```
SET @cmd = 'BCP "EXECUTE [F0902].[D365O].[Get-F0911NewRecordsByBatchNumber] '+ cast(@JDEBatchNumber as varchar(64))+'" QUERYOUT "D:\D365O\DataSource\F0911\Input\'+@TimeStamp+'.csv" -c -t\^, -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME + ''
```

Although, I think this is more what you want...

```
SET @cmd = 'BCP "EXECUTE [F0902].[D365O].[Get-F0911NewRecordsByBatchNumber] '''+ cast(@JDEBatchNumber as varchar(64))+''' QUERYOUT "D:\D365O\DataSource\F0911\Input\'+@TimeStamp+'.csv" -c -t\^, -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME + ''
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. the first script I got an error with the export, it didn't export the second script I got the following usage: BCP {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]

Comment: You are going to have to figure out the quotation marks for your BCP. It seems like you may be missing " at the end since you have BCP "Execute... but no closing "